How to use datemodified for incremental loads?
I have a power bi dataset that I need to incrementally load.
The source data has the date modified column.
So if I set to last 90 days in the incremental load settings, then power bi will delete and reinsert last 90 days of date modified data.
But if the data row was last modified say on the 100th day, then power bi refresh will duplicate this row? How to handle this situation?

With a 90-day incremental refresh configured, the 100-day old record would not be picked up because it's outside the refresh range. The existing record from a previous refresh will remain unchanged.
The Detect Data Changes section of the incremental load documentation indirectly lists approaches to this issue when it addresses cardinality and memory consumption:

Use a power query (M) function to persist the latest value.
Using XMLA scripts to pre-process records however you like during incremental load (of course, it doesn't tell you it's for Premium Subscription only)
Offloading the task to a separate ETL process (ADF, Databricks, etc), having it flag the data PBI should consume. This is what I do to centralize data validation and avoid implementing unique solutions for every data consumer.


How does this prevent duplication
